# How to create dummies from list with multiple values and predefined categories?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dummy-variable

I'd like to transform this :

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
      label
0     (a, e)
1     (a, d)
2       (b,)
3     (d, e)
```

to This :

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  0  0  1
1  1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  1  1
```

As you can see there are predefined columns, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' and c is empty but still exists.

I tried multiple things like this : df.str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
first without all the columns just to get the dummies with multiple values in the input but I want to add the predefined columns thing to it.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is your `label` columns a series of tuples or of strings?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new DataFrame, then `stack` + `get_dummies`. `any` along the original index for the dummies.

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame([*df.label], index=df.index).stack()).any(level=0).astype(int)

   a  b  d  e
0  1  0  0  1
1  1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  1
```

---

Because you have pre-defined columns, we can reindex and fill missing with 0.

```
res = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame([*df.label], index=df.index).stack()).any(level=0)
res = res.reindex(list('abcde'), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

#   a  b  c  d  e
#0  1  0  0  0  1
#1  1  0  0  1  0
#2  0  1  0  0  0
#3  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you !! 
It worked when I used 
df.str.join('|').str.get_dummies() and then 

df.reindex(columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'], fill_value=0)

Answer (score 3):

Good practice for `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

print (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['label']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index))
```

Comment: I find the answer, thank you very much I'll keep that in mind for the next time

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['label'].str.join(sep='*').str.get_dummies(sep='*')
```

Comment: Thank you ! :) The only problem is that it won't create the 'c' column as shown in my example, I found the solution it's in the comment of the first answer